# How to parse an xml file using jquery without missing html tags like <p>,<b> included in it?

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have an xml file and i am trying to parse it using jquery.On reading through jquery, i am getting an output as a single string, not as the required format.

I am having an xml file like,

```
                <p>The

                    <b>

                        <i>maximum</i>

                    </b>allowable incentive.</p>

                <p>

                    <b>Medicare Incentives</b>

                </p>

                <p>For Medicare, to receive</p>

                <p>

                    <b>Medicare Disincentives</b>

                </p>

                <p>Beginning in 2015, Medicare EPs </p>
```

this.

My code look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/XMLRead/chapter01.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('page').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('li');
                console.log('id ' + id);
                if (id == '1.3.1.1') {
                    var data = $(this).find('content-text').text();
                    console.log('data ' + data);
                    $(this).find('content-text').clone().appendTo('#left-container');

                }
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your trying to get a DOM object back intead of a XML object, but if you are you probably want to look at the Javascript Dom Parser http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
      parser=new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
      xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async=false;
      xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
  }
```